# Material-ui SpeedDialAction OnClick function is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I put file Input trigger on material-ui SpeedDialAction but it does not work.

```
const hiddenAddReceipt = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const hiddenAddPhoto = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

return (
<>
 <SpeedDial
                    ariaLabel="SpeedDial basic example"
                    sx={{ position: "absolute", color: "#fb8278", zIndex: 1 }}
                    className={styles.addIcon}
                    icon={<NoteAddOutlinedIcon />}
                    direction={"right"}
                    open={speedDialOpen}
                    onClose={() => setSpeedDialOpen(false)}
                    onOpen={() => setSpeedDialOpen(true)}
                  >
                    <SpeedDialAction
                      key={"photo"}
                      icon={<CameraAltOutlinedIcon />}
                      tooltipTitle={"add photo"}
                      onClick={() => {
                        if (hiddenAddPhoto.current) {
                          hiddenAddPhoto.current.click();
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                    <SpeedDialAction
                      key={"receipt"}
                      icon={<TextSnippetOutlinedIcon />}
                      tooltipTitle={"add receipt"}
                      onClick={() => {
                        if (hiddenAddReceipt.current) {
                          hiddenAddReceipt.current.click();
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                  </SpeedDial>
<Button
              variant="contained"
              className={styles.addReceipt}
              onClick={() => {
                if (hiddenAddReceipt.current) {
                  hiddenAddReceipt.current.click();
                }
              }}
            >
              <div className={styles.logo}>
                <TextSnippetOutlinedIcon />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.text}>Add Receipt</div>
            </Button>
            <input
              id="hiddenAddReceiptInput"
              type="file"
              onChange={() => {
                alert("receipt is added");
              }}
              ref={hiddenAddReceipt}
              style={{ display: "none" }}
            />

            <Button
              variant="contained"
              className={styles.addPhoto}
              onClick={() => {
                if (hiddenAddPhoto.current) {
                  hiddenAddPhoto.current.click();
                }
              }}
            >
              <div className={styles.logo}>
                <CameraAltOutlinedIcon />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.text}>Add Photo</div>
            </Button>
     <input
              id="hiddenAddPhotoInput"
              type="file"
              onChange={() => {
                alert("photo is added");
              }}
              ref={hiddenAddPhoto}
              style={{ display: "none" }}
            />

</>
)
```

When I click on "Add photo"/ "Add receipt" button, it's triggering the input properly. However, I tried this same thing for material-ui speedDialAction but does not work.

I used `alert` and `console.log()` onCLick on speedDialAction to check and it\s giving proper response but does not open the input.